# Magento2 Braintree not showing on checkout when in Dev, Live and Test servers using either sandbox or production mode

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

We have setup a Braintree payment method and its working ok when on local but when we tried to setup it in our dev, test and live sites the Braintree is not showing on checkout page using either sandbox or production mode. Does anyone have the same issue and solved it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have entered proper data like.
merchant account id:
merchant id:
publickey:
private key:

Because in magento2 that field sequence is changed.And check currency because braintree require different "merchant account id" for different type of currency.